# Trouble using drake build with Gurobi enabled

Tags: drake

I am trying to build drake from source in order to use the Gurobi solver, and have followed the instructions to build from source using Bazel.

When building and testing, using the suggested `bazel test --config gurobi --test_tag_filters=gurobi //...`, it responds that all tests pass, indicating that the build is successful.

I changed the include dir from `/opt/drake` to `/home/melyso/drake` (path to the cloned repo) in the `CmakeLists.txt` file. The project builds successfully. However, when printing `drake::solvers::GurobiSolver::is_available()` to the terminal, I get back 0, i.e. false. What might I be doing incorrectly here?

Comment: To be clear, you should be pointing to something like `/home/melyso/drake/install`, right?  

I hope you've seen the examples here:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main/drake_cmake_installed

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply! I hadn't found this set of examples previously, and things seem to work as expected after following this installation guide.